# C++ Compile source file from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cl

I need to compile a external source file from Visual Studio.
I picked that from the developer command prompt:

```
cl /EHsc test.cpp
```

So I tried this:

```
system("cl /EHsc test.cpp");
```

But the command 'cl' doesn't exist in the normal cmd that is called by system()

Any suggestions how to use the compiler function anyway?

Comment: `cl.exe` is part of Visual Studio. Have you checked your `PATH` variable?

Comment: Why do you need to do this from a c++ program actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Skynet? ;-)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to compile a piece of cpp from a running piece of code in Visual Studio? If so, then cl will do that for you, but it will need to be on the system path and might need some environment variables set as well. Use the Visual Studio Administrator Command Prompt and then type 'set' to see what the environment is set to.

Comment: @TheWelder Yes, I can see it. But I don't know what I should do next.
Any idea?

Comment: Please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505362/cl-exe-not-finding-any-standard-include-file)

Comment: @AndreasDM yes you are right, but I noticed that the Functions from cl.exe will be lost after  running the compiled executable instead of the Visual Studio debugger. That  means I think even If I would change the variables, I wouldn't get the result there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I did it myself and for those ones who are curious I did it by making a copy of  the vcvars32.bat and added a few commands like this:

```html
cd %~dp0%

cl /LD source.cpp /EHsc ;remember putting this part after the bat-file called all important commands
```

Now I just need to execute this file from c++ and here we go.