# Include Standard Libraries with cl.exe (in vanilla Command Prompt)?

Tags: c++, std

I'm attempting to compile a simple shared library DLL file with a standard Windows Command Prompt command.

The DLL file will get compiled from the following C++ file called `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int test_fx(void)
{
    std::cout << "test\n";
    return 0;
}
```

While I'm able to compile this C++ file into a DLL with `cl.exe` without issues using the Visual Studio 2022 Native Command Prompt, which has all the environment variable setup correctly, attempting to do the same in a regular Windows Command Prompt results in the following:

```
test.cpp
test.cpp(1): fatal error C1034: iostream: no include path set
```

I understand that the regular Windows Command Prompt does not have all the required environment variables setup, and that I have to probably specify each library I'm using individually with linked flags and such.

I attempted to follow the answer to [the following simillar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505362/cl-exe-not-finding-any-standard-include-file), yet the command `vcvars32.bat` and `vcvars32` are unrecognized commands in my Command Prompt.

What is the proper way to include all the C++ standard library paths & environment variables for a vanilla Windows Command Prompt? What would be the linker flags for libraries such as `iostream`?

Comment: In the start menu, there should be an entry to start a VS command prompt, with all the paths and such already setup. Try that.

Comment: I think the proper way is to use a developer command prompt. But [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170#path_and_environment) is the best documentation I could find from Microsoft

Comment: The reason I want to use the vanilla Command Prompt is because I'm launching it via the `CreateProcess` Windows API function, which can only launch a vanilla CMD. I cannot launch a VS Native Command Prompt with `CreateProcess`, so I have to set all the environment variables myself.

Comment: You need to find the vcvars bat files in your visual studio installation and run them (that's all the developer command prompt does)

Comment: @Runsva Maybe you could create a project file (or a solution file) and launch msbuild instead. That seems a lot easier.

Comment: @AlanBirtles shouldn't that file be in the `%PATH%` environment variable already though when I installed Visual Studio? I guess that's the only way.....

Comment: no, at least it isn't on my machine

Comment: @Runsva - what you are missing isn't a simple include or library path or two... The Developer Command Prompt environment setup is hundreds if not thousands of lines long. You can actually look at the actual environment file in the `\Program Data\...\VC\Auxiliary\Build` directory for VS (many directories down) and the names are like `vcvars32.bat`, `vcvars64.bat`, ... `vcvarsall.bat`. It's not worth rolling-your-own, just use the VS provided command prompts. If you are talking about having a user on another box use your `.dll`, that's another matter.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 0):

While the preferred and simpler way is to use the developer command prompt (as mentioned in the comments), it is still possible to build a DLL by invoking `cl.exe` straight from the regular command line.

To prepare for that, I suggest you to start the developer command prompt once, type `SET` there, and take notes of the paths specified in the following environment variables: `INCLUDE`, `LIBPATH`, `LIB`, and also the versions specified in the variables `VCToolsVersion` and `WindowsSDKVersion`.

Then you'll need to construct the complete command line for the `cl.exe` invocation. The following pages describe the MSVC command-line options:

- [Compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=msvc-170)
- [Compiler-controlled linker options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-controlled-link-options?view=msvc-170)
- [Linker reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linking?view=msvc-170)
- [Linker options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=msvc-170)

You have mentioned using `CreateProcess` to execute `cl.exe` programmatically, so here is an example program doing that (requires at least C++17, since I use `std::filesystem` for path manipulations):

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "windows.h"

using std::wstring;
using std::vector;

template <typename T>
wstring concat_with_prefixes(const wstring& prefix, const vector<T>& vec)
{
    wstring result;
    for (const auto& item : vec)
    {
        result += L" " + prefix + L"\"" + item.c_str() + L"\"";
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    using std::filesystem::path;

    const path my_source_code_folder{ LR"(C:\MyTestApplications\MyDLL)" };
    const wstring my_cpp_file_name{ L"test.cpp" };
    const wstring my_obj_file_name{ L"test.obj" };
    const wstring my_dll_file_name{ L"MyDLL.dll" };

    const wstring msvc_toolset_version{ L"14.29.30133" };
    const wstring win_sdk_version{ L"10.0.19041.0" };

    const path msvc_folder
    {
        path{LR"(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC)"}
        / msvc_toolset_version
    };
    const path win_sdk_base_folder{ LR"(C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10)" };

    const path win_sdk_include_folder{ win_sdk_base_folder / L"include" / win_sdk_version};
    const path win_sdk_references_folder{ win_sdk_base_folder / L"References" / win_sdk_version};
    const path win_sdk_lib_folder{ win_sdk_base_folder / L"lib" / win_sdk_version};

    const wstring prefix_include{ L"/I " };
    const vector<path> include_folders // Normally taken from the "INCLUDE" environment variable
    {
        msvc_folder / LR"(ATLMFC\include)",
        msvc_folder / LR"(include)",
        win_sdk_include_folder / LR"(ucrt)",
        win_sdk_include_folder / LR"(shared)",
        win_sdk_include_folder / LR"(um)"
    };

    const wstring prefix_define{ L"/D " };
    const vector<wstring> preprocessor_definitions
    {
        L"WIN32",
        L"_USRDLL",
        L"_WINDLL",
        L"_UNICODE",
        L"UNICODE",
        L"NDEBUG",
        L"MYDLL_EXPORTS"
    };

    const wstring compiler_options
    {
        L"/permissive- /W4 /WX /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:inline /Zc:forScope /fp:precise "
        L"/GS /Gy /O2 /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /FC /EHsc /diagnostics:column /analyze- /LD"
    };

    const wstring prefix_libpath{ L"/LIBPATH:" };
    const vector<path> lib_folders // Normally from the "LIBPATH" and "LIB" environment variables
    {
        msvc_folder / LR"(ATLMFC\lib\x86)",
        msvc_folder / LR"(lib\x86)",
        msvc_folder / LR"(lib\x86\store\references)",
        win_sdk_references_folder,
        win_sdk_lib_folder / LR"(ucrt\x86)",
        win_sdk_lib_folder / LR"(um\x86)",
    };

    const wstring libraries{ LR"("kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "advapi32.lib")" };

    const path cl_exe{ msvc_folder / LR"(bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe)" };

    wstring command_line{ L'"' + cl_exe.wstring() + L'"'};
    command_line += concat_with_prefixes(prefix_include, include_folders)
        + concat_with_prefixes(prefix_define, preprocessor_definitions)
        + L' ' + compiler_options
        + L" /Fo\"" + my_obj_file_name + L'"'
        + L" /Fe\"" + my_dll_file_name + L'"'
        + L" \"" + my_cpp_file_name + L'"'
        + L" /link"
        + concat_with_prefixes(prefix_libpath, lib_folders)
        + L' ' + libraries;
    command_line.resize(UNICODE_STRING_MAX_CHARS + 1);

    STARTUPINFOW si{};
    si.cb = sizeof si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi{};

    if (!::CreateProcessW(cl_exe.c_str(), data(command_line),
        nullptr, nullptr, false, 0, nullptr, my_source_code_folder.c_str(), &si, &pi))
    {
        ::MessageBoxW(nullptr,
            (L"Cannot start the compiler/linker driver process due to system error "
                + std::to_wstring(::GetLastError())).c_str(), nullptr, MB_OK);
    }

    ::WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    ::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    ::CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

As you see, there are many constants, like paths and versions, that you'll have to find out and "configure" according to your system. In my example code above, the command line ends up like this:

> `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" /D "WIN32" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "NDEBUG" /D "MYDLL_EXPORTS" /permissive- /W4 /WX /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:inline /Zc:forScope /fp:precise /GS /Gy /O2 /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /FC /EHsc /diagnostics:column /analyze- /LD /Fo"test.obj" /Fe"MyDLL.dll" "test.cpp" /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\lib\x86" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86\store\references" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "advapi32.lib"`

But on your system, it will probably be different, because of the different toolset/SDK versions, of course.